# Initialize object with empty array parameter in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typeorm

I have an **Icon** entity which has a list of **Category**:

```
import { Entity, Column, ManyToMany } from "typeorm";
import { ObjectType, Field } from "type-graphql";

import { Base } from "./Base";
import { Category } from "./Category";

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Icon extends Base {

    @Field()
    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Field(() => [Category])
    @ManyToMany(() => Category, category => category.icons)
    categories: Category[];
}
```

In my mutation in **IconResolver**:

```
@Mutation(() => Icon!)
  async createIcon(
    @Arg("input") input: CreateIconInput
  ): Promise<Icon> {
    return  Icon.create(input).save();
  }
```

With an input type:

```
@InputType()
class CreateIconInput implements Partial<Icon> {
  @Field() name!: string;
}
```

If I run the mutation in Apollo GraphQL Client

```
mutation
{
createIcon(input:{name: "Ice cream" code: "icecream_Cone" })
  { 
    id 
    name 
    categories
    {
      id 
      name
    } 
  }
}
```

I get the error:

> $"Cannot return null for non-nullable field Icon.categories."$

How would I initialize the category array to be an empty array instead of null? I have tried to put code in the `createIcon` function that creates a new `Icon`, copies the parameters from input to the new `Icon`, changes the `item.categories` array to an empty `Category` array, and then saves that new item instead of the input. However, this does not work, which seems very weird as it should save the empty array.
Is there something wrong in the entity definition?